# What's the meaning of "I needed them to mean nothing."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know the meaning of every words of the sentence below but I cannot understand the meaning of the words together:

> I needed them to mean nothing.

Is there any structure like this: need someone/something to do something?

---

The full text is here:

> I STOPPED GOING TO my French group, then to my sketching class.
>   Instead of reading in the library or attending lectures, I watched TV
>   in my room, working my way through every popular series from the past
>   two decades. When one episode ended, I would begin the next without
>   thinking, the way one breath follows another. I watched TV eighteen or
>   twenty hours a day. When I slept I dreamed of home, and at least once
>   a week I awoke standing in the street in the middle of the night,
>   wondering if it was my own cry that I’d heard just before waking. I
>   did not study. I tried to read but the sentences meant nothing. **I
>   needed them to mean nothing.** I couldn’t bear to string sentences into
>   strands of thought, or to weave those strands into ideas. Ideas were
>   too similar to reflection, and my reflections were always of the
>   expression on my father’s stretched face the moment before he’d fled
>   from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any structure like this: need someone/something to do something?

Yes, there is. It is not easy to find in the dictionaries, because the someone, something is a bit vague. You can use it about a non-specific person:

> I need someone to tidy up my garden
>   I need somebody to design a web site for me

or a specific person:

> I need John to pick me up from the station

You can use it about a non-specific thing:

> I need something to get the stains out of this dress
>   I need something to calm me down

or a specific thing

> I need the text to be a bit bigger
>   I need the spreadsheet to give me the totals for each department

---

> I needed them to mean nothing

This text is written by somebody that has psychological issues. Many people in this state want to cut themselves off from everything. She feels that she should do something and tries to read, but does not want to take in any information from what she reads. She wants/needs the sentences that she reads to have no meaning.

Comment: Many thanks! And what about the original question? (the meaning of "I needed them to mean nothing.")

Comment: @Peace, I have updated my answer